# POS for .NET Barcode scanner DeviceEnabled failed to set

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, opos, pos-for-.net

I'm currently developing a .NET 4.5.1 application that should use a barcode scanner to read 2D barcode text. For that, Microsoft POS for .NET 1.14.1 is installed and used. The barcode sanner (Intermec/Honeywell ED40) driver is correctly installed, the OPOS driver is an unmanaged OCX.

I use the typical workflow to create a scanner instance in a WinForms project:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  private PosExplorer _explorer;
  private Scanner     _scanner;

  public MainForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnShown(e);

    _explorer = new PosExplorer(this);
    DeviceInfo  device = myPosExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.Scanner, "Intermec_RS-232_Scanner");
    _scanner = (Scanner)explorer.CreateInstance(device);
    _scanner.Open();
    _scanner.Claim(1000);
    _scanner.DataEvent += scanner_DataEvent;
    _scanner.ErrorEvent += scanner_ErrorEvent;
    _scanner.DeviceEnabled = true; // throws here if normal user privileges
    _scanner.DataEventEnabled = true;
    _scanner.DecodeData = true;
  }
}
```

Everything works fine if the application is started using administrative rights. But, if it is started using normal user rights, the scanner cannot be enabled. When executing the `scanner.DeviceEnabled = true` statement, the following exception is thrown:

```
PosControlException: Failed to set property DeviceEnabled.
```

The same issue occurs, if I compile and start the provided Microsoft sample "Microsoft POS Tester". But the also provided, precompiled version "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Point Of Service\SDK\Samples\Sample Application\TestApp.exe" directory works, independent from the privileges.

I did not found a solution in different forums and in the POS for .NET documentation. I did several experiments with the Internet Explorer security settings for ActiveX, same problem. I guess, it is a security setting elsewere, has anybody an idea?

Environment:

- Windows 7 Pro x64
- .NET 4.5.1

Thanks.

**Edit:**

After many hours, I have found the reason, it was registry virtualization. The OPOS driver (OCX) of the manufacturer tries to write to the *HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Intermec* subkey. So, that write access was virtualized to *HKEY_USERS/[User SID]_Classes/VirtualStore/Machine/Software/Wow6432Node/Intermec*. But the key in the virtual store was incomplete, many values were missing.

**Solution:**

- Delete the *HKEY_USERS/[User SID]_Classes/VirtualStore/Machine/Software/Wow6432Node/Intermec* key in the virtual store.
- Assign *Full access* permissions to the Windows *Users* group for the original *HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Intermec* key. So, all users access the identical registry key.

Comment: Note that you can answer your own question, can you edit out the answer from the question and do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved, see my edit above.